# React Testing Library: Why does the order of the tests matter?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here's a [link to codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-beaver-zt1nm?file=/src/__tests__/Counter.test.js)

Reordering the below tests would make `find one after the other` test to pass.

Another way to make it pass would be to make `should be able to find 3 directly` test to pass, for example, by making it find `2` instead of `3`.

```
describe("Counter", () => {
  test("should be able to find 3 directly", async () => {
    render(<Counter />);

    const three = await waitFor(() => screen.findByText(/3/i));
    expect(three).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test("find one after the other", async () => {
    render(<Counter />);

    const one = await waitFor(() => screen.findByText(/1/i));
    expect(one).toBeInTheDocument();

    const two = await waitFor(() => screen.findByText(/2/i));
    expect(two).toBeInTheDocument();

    const three = await waitFor(() => screen.findByText(/3/i));
    expect(three).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

So the question is, why does the order of the tests matter? Why is the [clean up](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-cleanup) not working?

Comment: `Counter` is using `setInterval` so it's basically luck that the second test passes. Usually any tests, react or not, that depend on specific dates/times, you would use [fake timers](https://testing-library.com/docs/using-fake-timers/) to specify/control increments in time. For counter, you would set the fake timers, then update time to say 3 seconds later so that then you can check that the text `3` appears.  Also you are likely not using setInterval correctly in your component [useInterval](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

Comment: I'll add that while there react testing library methods that can wait for text to appear, fake timers is how in jest, mocha, tape, or any other library, you would control the clock to ensure things are appearing/executing exactly how you expect them to be.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `waitFor` has reach its timeout as waiting for the counter to 3 which means it is unrelated to ordering in this case I guess.

You would fix by increase the timeout to wait your counter as following:

```js
test("should be able to find 3 directly", async () => {
  render(<Counter />);

  const three = await waitFor(() => screen.findByText(/3/i), {
    timeout: 3e3, // 3s wait would find 3
  });

  expect(three).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: I see, I was wrongly assuming the timeout period was 5 seconds. https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor

Comment: So why is the `"same as the first test but fails because the second test is failing"` test failing only when the `"should be able to find 3 directly"` test is failing?

Comment: Yeah that looks interesting. I guess it would throw error as one of `waitFor` reach its limit timeout in all executing test cases (since they are run in async)